# How do I add value in this setup in SQL?

Tags: sql

```
select r.rep_name, s.Rep_Cust_YTD from reps r, sales s
where r.rep_ID = s.rep_ID
```

---

I need to add up each `rep_Name`'s TOTAL `rep_cust_YTD` sales. I will then use group by to combine them, but I still need each to be the total.

I would add a picture to help better understand, but am not allowed to yet.

Comment: Can you show some data and expected result? And what's your DBMS? You might look for a `SUM(s.Rep_Cust_YTD) OVER (PARTITION BY r.rep_name)`

Answer (score 0):

First, switch to JOIN syntax, which is more commonly accepted now

```
select 
  r.rep_name, 
  s.Rep_Cust_YTD 
from reps r
INNER JOIN sales s 
  on r.rep_ID = s.rep_ID
```

To sum up values, `GROUP BY` `rep_name` and `SUM` up `Rep_Cust_YTD`:

```
select 
  r.rep_name, 
  SUM(s.Rep_Cust_YTD) Rep_YTD
from reps r
INNER JOIN sales s 
  on r.rep_ID = s.rep_ID
GROUP BY r.rep_name
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select r.rep_name, sum(s.Rep_Cust_YTD) as total 
from reps r join sales s 
on r.rep_ID = s.rep_ID
group by r.rep_name;
```

You need to add a `group by` clause to get the total per rep_name.